# How to show multiple users location in iOS project live?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to develop an app that would show the location of multiple users near you on a map in real time. Me and my friend were thinking of getting the users location every 1 min, then upload their current location to a database, then update that on the map, and show it on other people's map. Now we realize that this would consume so much data and time from the user, also that would create so much calling to the database which we are trying to limit. So my question is, how would I show multiple users location on the map in real time? Think of uber or lyft and how they display the driver's location and also many other driver's location to the user. How did they accomplish that or if there is away of creating a similar thing without the strain on the user's data.

Comment: They only pull the data about cars that are near to the user, and not the list of all cars globally.

Comment: Yea I know, I just used them as an example, and I just want to display different users' location that are near each other live. If you have a solution that would be great.

Comment: So what's your question then? Looks like you already know an approach to a solution.

Comment: The question would be, how to show multiple users' location on a map? But not to be too expensive on the user by uploading and grabbing their stored location from a database continually.

Comment: I thought you already figured that out. When you're querying your database, only retrieve those users' whose location is within some range that you're interested in, rather than fetching all location data

Comment: Yea that's what I had in mind and what we are doing, I just wanted to see if there is a way to make it less calling and retrieving from a database. Another user on this thread said I would do all of that in the background. Which was a great help.

Comment: "make it less calling and retrieving from a database" I'm not sure what that even means

Comment: So instead of getting data from the database every minute, to update the users' location, we can do it every large distance the user travels. That would be less calling the database and less data usage from the user. Because I don't want the user to finish all his cellular data in one go by uploading and retrieving data from and to the database.

Comment: Polling periodically would be a bad idea, it almost always is. I would make clients push their location up only when there's a significant change. When the backend receives that update, it can use it as an opportunity to push updates to the nearby users. This way, the whole system is push-based, only transmitting locations when meaningful. It's still "retrieving data from a database", though

Comment: I understand we will still uploading and retrieving from the database, and that's what we will do, only uploading the location when a significant change happens, like a large distance was traveled. Like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to be followed -

1. Get location of the user not after every 1 minute or specific time but get location as per user moves. Get their location by using Significant-Change Location.
2. To get multiple users data - you must be storing data of other users, so get those data in background thread. **Don't** use main thread to get data but use main thread to display the data.
3. If you want store data into local database, so that if user is offline he does not looses any data.

PS: **Start small scale then go for large scale**. Don't think of handling data into large scale like uber at first. So start with 5 users and updating data into application every specific time( this is not for fetching user location but to showing data of users)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can definitely work with this. And yea I understand what you mean, I wasn't going to make it on a large scale like Uber, i just used them as an example.

Comment: I can totally understand because I was in your shoes few years back. And made the similar app.

Comment: oh thats awesome, do you mind if I ask you questions if I got stuck on something in the future?

And thank you again

Comment: No prob at all. Anytime!

Comment: Thank you for that